# Let $f(x) = x^2$ if $x\leq 8$, and let $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ otherwise. What is $\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{f^{(i)}(2)}{i}$?

Tags: limits

Consider the following $2$-player abstract game played on a calculator, the current input of which is $2$. The goal of **Player A** is to make the input as large as possible, and the goal of **Player B** is to make the number on the calculator's screen as small as possible.  **Player A** presses the 'square function' button if the calculator's value is at most $8$, and **Player B** presses the 'cube root function' button otherwise, and the two players continue this process *ad infinitum*. This process is illustrated below. Then what is the average value on the calculator's screen?

**Player A** $\longrightarrow 4$

**Player A** $\longrightarrow 16$

**Player B** $\longrightarrow 2.51984209...$

**Player A** $\longrightarrow 6.34960420...$

**Player A** $\longrightarrow 40.3174735...$

**Player B** $\longrightarrow 3.42897593...$

etc.

Letting $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be as defined above, it is clear that the value of the calculator's screen after $i$ turns is $f^{(i)}(2)$. So it is natural to consider the average value given by the following expression: $$\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{f^{(i)}(2)}{i} \approx 11.6$$ 
Is there a closed-form expression for this limit?

Also, on average, how frequently is it the turn of **Player A**?

Comment: You mean $f^i$, not $f^{(i)}$. The latter is a derivative.

Comment: @Element118 Given a mapping $f\colon S \to S$, the iterate of $f$ with itself $n$ times is often denoted $f^{(n)} = f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_dynamics, for example.